# AMP-IMG expande las imágenes en Mobile

Tags: imagen, img, amp

Tengo un sitio web en el que implementé **amp**, y la situación a resolver es poder tener el control de qué imágenes permitir que amp expanda al hacerle click y qué imagen, bloquear esa expansión.

Este comportamiento es en **Mobile**

En otras palabras, lo que necesito es saber cómo deshabilitar la expansión de imágenes para el componente **amp-img**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta no es la solución más elegante pero funciona bastante bien.

Por defecto amp, agregaba la apertura de un **lightbox** en el evento tap de la imagen. Sería este evento dentro del tag **amp-img**:

```
on="tap:amp-lightbox-gallery.activate"
```

Entonces, si directamente yo le agrego el evento pero que no haga nada (un *focus* por ejemplo, también puede ser un *show*), no injecta la expansión de la imagen, mi código quedó así:

```
<amp-img alt="image" src="assets/isotipo.svg"
         id="myImg" on="tap:myImg.show" 
         width="54" height="54" role="button" tabindex="0"
         layout="fixed"></amp-img>
```

Y con eso quedó solucionado.
No olvidar agregar *role="button" tabindex="0"*, es obligatorio para amp, agregar esas propiedades para una imagen con el evento tap.

Espero que a alguno le sirva. Saludos!